# Export data of states arays to csv file in react hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, export-csv

I would like to know how it is in React.js Hooks possible to save  each state of the functional state (Hier History states) **as arrays** in csv file? I want to save each turns of tic tac toe game as an array, but i don't know how?

````
  **const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);**
  const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState(0);
  const [xIsNext, setXisNext] = useState(true);
  const winner = calculateWinner(history[stepNumber]);
  const xO = xIsNext ? "X" : "O";```
````

Comment: if you do write a file in react, it will force the browser to download it. Is this what you want?